# How to insulate around an electrical panel?

Tags: insulation, electrical-panel

I’m insulating and putting sheet rock on my garage walls. This is the outside wall and the back side of the electrical meter panel.

[image]

The large wire bundle going out of it runs through my attic to my breaker box on the opposite wall. I was wondering the best way to insulate around the box. I planed on using batt insulation and cutting out the space for the box. Is there a better way? Also is there any safety concern or rules about spacing of insulation near the panel?

Comment: What's inside the box?  If it's wire junctions (wire nuts) or something similar, circuit breakers, fuses, etc, the box cannot be buried behind sheetrock.

Comment: Question states that it's the back of the meter box (accessible from the front, outside, presumably.)

Comment: Ahhh, must have missed that part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have some space between the meter box and the face of the sheetrock (I think you do but pictures can be misleading) then a sheet of rigid foam insulation of that thickness may give you a bit more insulation right over the box than you'd get from that much fiberglass, or just leaving a hole in the insulation over the box.

Should be no issue with insulation touching the box.

Comment: Unfortunately its flush with the backside of the wall so no room for rigid insulation behind it. I’m having to use firing strips to just get the drywall in place as it actually is about 1/8th if an inch deeper than the frame of the wall. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a picture frame around the box - basically building the wall framing out enough that you can get a piece of foam insulating board on top of the back of the box.  Even 1/2" of polyisocyanurate (R=3.2) plus the plywood sheathing and the sheetrock is going to give you less heat loss than that window the box is next to.